# java imageicon and frame

Tags: imageicon

```
coins = new JPanel();
    coins.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    ImageIcon tenP1 = new ImageIcon("10p.jpeg");
    tenP = new JButton("", tenP1);
    ImageIcon twentyP1 = new ImageIcon("20p.jpeg");
    twentyP = new JButton("", twentyP1);
    ImageIcon fiftyP1 = new ImageIcon("50p.jpeg");
    fiftyP = new JButton("", fiftyP1);
    ImageIcon pound = new ImageIcon("pound.jpeg");
    onePound = new JButton("", pound);
```

MY Image Icon do not display and I have them in the same directory same name ? please help

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

`public static void main(String[] args) {`

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test image");
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(TestImage.class.getResource("/img.png"));
    ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon(TestImage.class.getResource("/img2.png"));
    ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(TestImage.class.getResource("/img3.png"));
    ImageIcon img4 = new ImageIcon(TestImage.class.getResource("/img4.png"));
    ImageIcon img5 = new ImageIcon(TestImage.class.getResource("/img5.png"));`

    JButton testBut = new JButton(img);
    JButton testBut2 = new JButton(img2);
    JButton testBut3 = new JButton(img3);
    JButton testBut4 = new JButton(img4);
    JButton testBut5 = new JButton(img5);

    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pane.add(testBut,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane.add(testBut2,BorderLayout.WEST);
    pane.add(testBut3,BorderLayout.EAST);
    pane.add(testBut4,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pane.add(testBut5,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.add(pane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

`

Comment: ive added them to panels and container but just displays noral buttons

Comment: I think you should tru with thisto instance your ImageIcon : [code] ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getRessource("/img.png"));

Comment: ok thanks any idea how to use between operator on switch statement in case, so for example case ((hours>=0)&&(hours<2)):amount = 0.50 would that work

Comment: Up to 2 hours 50p; 
2 to 4 hours £1;
4 to 8 hours £2;
8 to 12 hours £3;
12 to 24 hours £5; make hours as cases without having to put many cases?  public double balance(int hours) {
      
     double amount = 0.00;
     switch (hours) {
     
     
     case ((hours>=0)&&(hours<2)):  amount = 0.50;
           break;
     
     return amount;
     
     
     }
       
    }

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks any idea how to use between operator on switch statement in case, so for example case ((hours>=0)&&(hours<2)):amount = 0.50 would that work 
Up to 2 hours 50p; 2 to 4 hours £1; 4 to 8 hours £2; 8 to 12 hours £3; 12 to 24 hours £5; – 
You can create a enum with your range :

`public enum Hours {`

`U2,2TO4,4TO8,8TO12,12TO24;`

}`

`Hours value = HOURS.value`  // just an example , you have to get it with a getter

`swicth(value){`
`case: U2  :`/action

`case 2TO4 :`/action

`case 4TO8 :`/action

}

..

Comment: the hours is passed as arguement

Comment: you can add a function which takes your argument and return your HOURS Value: